# Javascript resize image before upload - read from canvas - image there, width and height 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I am currently trying to resize images before the upload and to achieve this I am using JS/Jquery, has to be client side. On my server I simply deny all requests which are bigger then 30MB.

I am using this code:

```
    $( "input[type='file']" ).change(function() {

        console.log("function works");

        // from an input element
        var filesToUpload = this.files;
        console.log(filesToUpload);

        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]);

        console.log("image: ", img);
        console.log("the image is: ", img.width);

        var MAX_WIDTH = 800;
        var MAX_HEIGHT = 600;
        var width = img.width;
        var height = img.height;

        if (width > height) {
          if (width > MAX_WIDTH) {
            height *= MAX_WIDTH / width;
            width = MAX_WIDTH;
          }
        } else {
          if (height > MAX_HEIGHT) {
            width *= MAX_HEIGHT / height;
            height = MAX_HEIGHT;
          }
        }

        canvas = $("#uploading_canvas").get(0);;

        canvas.width = width;
        canvas.height = height;
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);

        var dataurl = canvas[0].toDataURL("image/png");

        //var file = canvas.mozGetAsFile("foo.png");
    });
```

The first `console.log` output shows that the image is there, but somehow it has no width or height. Uploading an image with this code doesnt change anything atm.

Here are the console log outputs:

[image]

DataToUrl is undefined because the image is missing?

Comment: Nope... just because the image needs time to load.. and that is why you should use your code inside the  **onload event** of your image :)

Comment: Thanks, that solved the issue, I wrapped the remainig code into '$( img ).load(function() { ... '

Comment: great! thanks for the feedback... feel free to share your fix - that may help someone out there one day :)

Comment: if you want you can post an answer, I will accept then, otherwise I will do it and give you credit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @ymz explained in the comments the image needs time to load, so wrapping the image related code into an additional onload function solved the issue.

The solution looks like this:

```
        $( img ).load(function() {

            canvas = $("#uploading_canvas").get(0);


            var MAX_WIDTH = 600;
            var MAX_HEIGHT = 450;
            var width = img.width;
            var height = img.height;

            if (width > height) {
              if (width > MAX_WIDTH) {
                height *= MAX_WIDTH / width;
                width = MAX_WIDTH;
              }
            } else {
              if (height > MAX_HEIGHT) {
                width *= MAX_HEIGHT / height;
                height = MAX_HEIGHT;
              }
            }       

            canvas.width = width;
            canvas.height = height;
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);

            var dataurl = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

         });
```

Comment: this kind of posts are very useful to the stackoverflow community... you've got my up-vote!